# Table column with headers change column width

Tags: html, css, width

[HTML viewable at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/xNfhg/1/) (it's a lot of code to post here)

The method to change the column width escapes me, I'd like the "Produkt" column to be wider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this attribute to your header of that cell, it should force the entire column to be at least 100px:

```
<th id="produkttext" style="width: 100px;">Produkt</th>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, I shall see if there are any other CSS rules overriding it.

Comment: Hmmm, okay then. Have a look at this page explaining the `<td>` width attribute --> http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_td_width.asp

Comment: Nothing is working, have looked through and found no inherited widths, add `.mytable td{ width:16%;}` and change the width fro produkttext and pris. Not working so well.

Comment: Can you verify that your entire HTML / CSS validates through the w3c validator?

Comment: These are the only errors; http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.euroworker.no/order/&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Hmmmm, okay fair enough. I might be able to have a closer look a bit later on.

Comment: Thanks. I'll fix something else then :)

Comment: Did you get it sorted in the end Kyle?